# Scala Class parameters

Tags: scala

I have recently come across a Scala class in my project which has parameters like currying. For Example:

```
class A (a:Int,b:Int)(c:Int){
/** 
Some definition
**/
}
```

1. What is the advantage of these kind of parameterization?
2. When I create an object as 
   `val obj = new A(10,20)`

I am getting runtime error.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Super-quick answer: if you know `a` and `b` but don't yet know `c`, it may be beneficial to partially-build an instance of `A`, that can be given to something that can finish the job

Answer (score 2):

> What is the advantage of these kind of parameterization?

I can think of two possible advantages:

1. Delayed construction.

You can construct part of the instance in one area of the code base...

```
val almostA = new A(10, 20)(_)
```

...and complete it in a different area of the code.

```
val realA = almostA(30)
```

2. Default parameter value.

Your example doesn't do this, but a curried parameter can reference an earlier parameter.

```
class A (a:Int,b:Int)(c:Int = a){ . . .
```

> When I create an object as `val obj = new A(10,20)` I am getting runtime error.

You should be getting a compile-time error. You either have to complete the constructor parameters, `new A(10,20)(30)`, or you have to leave a placeholder, `new A(10,20)(_)`. You can leave the 2nd parameter group off only if it has a default value (see #2 above).

Comment: The first isn't a reason for currying, because you can do exactly the same without currying: `val almostA = new A(10, 20, _)`. It's more relevant for methods where currying can simplify syntax.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov; excellent point. I couln't make that compile but now I realize why. Type ascription is required: `almostA = new A(10, 20, _:Int)`